# counting number of users logged into linux

Tags: command-line, users

I am trying to display only the number of users that have logged into a machine on a certain day (depending on the day they run the bash shell program on)

Comment: To be clear, you want the number of users logged in on a particular day and not the users currently logged in, correct?

Answer (score 0):

use the `who` command [(man)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/who.1.html) for users currently logged in.

Edit:
If you want past logins use the `last` command [(man)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/last.1.html)

`last --since today`

Comment: I believe he wants the users who have logged in on a particular day. `who` gives the users who are currently logged in.

Comment: Thanks, the "when script is run" confused me. Answer is updated